# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que mi banner se mueva?

Tags: bash, script

Estoy realizando un script y en la presentación de mi script le quiero poner un banner, quiero que el banner el tren se mueva.

```
#!/bin/bash

clear
echo
echo 
echo "
      ___
 _][__| |
<_______|-
  O-O-O"
```

Comment: no está claro qué pretendes. Intenta proporcionar un [mcve]

Comment: Estoy haciendo un script y  lo pondré un banner de presentáncion , quiero que mi banner el tren se mueva

Comment: ¿Qué tiene que ver el tren en movimiento con pasar un parámetro? ¿Qué parámetro quieres pasar? Es eso lo que no queda claro

Comment: Quería llegar a dar un ejemplo  sobre el movimiento  que realizaba en el primer script

Comment: Nose si se pueda llegar hacer que el tren  ```se mueva```   lo quiero para mi prestación  de un script que estoy realizando , me siento mal por no encontrar la forma :c

Comment: Hay muchos ejemplos allí afuera, ¿has investigado un poco?